# Is it possible to shutdown remote Computers without inputing the password?

Tags: linux, shell

I used the following bash to shutdown remote computers,but for each computer,I must input the password for it.Is it possible to input the password Automatically?

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t root@192.168.1.11 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.12 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.13 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.14 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.15 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.16 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.17 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.18 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.19 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.20 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.21 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.22 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.23 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.24 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.25 "sudo poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.26 "sudo poweroff"
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to put your id_rsa.pub into each host's .ssh/authorized_keys?

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting the the same command, you can also use a `for host in ...` or a `while read host ... < hosts.txt` [loop](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to. Since you are logging on as `root` there is absolutely no reason to use `sudo`, just run `poweroff` or (better) `shutdown -h` directly.

If for some reason not explained in your question you really do need `sudo`, use `sudo`'s `-S` option. From `man sudo`:

```
   -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read
               the password from the standard input
               instead of the terminal device.  The
               password must be followed by a newline
               character.
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t root@192.168.1.11 "echo PASSWORD1 | sudo -S poweroff"
ssh -t root@192.168.1.12 "echo PASSWORD2 | sudo -S poweroff"
```

Comment: Note that passing the password in this manner is a security risk. Just make sure you are aware of the implications. :)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid password entering use [ssh-keygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen) for authentication key creation and upload [public key](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/) to all your servers.
BTW, terdon right, if you root do not use `sudo`.

```
ssh root@192.168.1.11 poweroff
ssh root@192.168.1.12 poweroff
```